# Mostrar el último archivo

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy intentando sacar los archivos de una descarga pero solo necesito la última de ella.
Como podría hacerlo, este es mi código, aquí solo dice cuantos archivos tenemos:

```
File carpeta = new File("C\\Descarga");
String [] archivos = carpeta.list();
if(archivos == null || archivo.length ==0){
    System.out.println("no hay archivos");
}else {
 for(int i = 0; i < archivos.length; i++)
 System.out.println(archivos[i]);
}
```

Comment: A ver... javascript o java??? Porque se parecen tanto como un dromedario a un coche. Ambos se apoyan en 4 puntos, pero vaya... no intentes meterle gasolina al dromedario!

Comment: Perdón  es Java, ya está modificado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás leyendo los nombres de los archivos, no accediendo a los archivos en si mismos, con lo cual no tienes manera de *ordenar* la lista ni ver las fechas de modificación. Una forma rápida de coger el último modificado sería:

```
//Cogemos todos los archivos
File directory = new File("Ruta_Al_Directorio");
//Asegúrate de que la ruta es correcta, C\\Descarga NO es una ruta válida!
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
//Los ordenamos por orden de última modificación invertido, así el último será el primero
Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reversed());
//El primer elemento será el último modificado
File lastFile = files[0];
System.out.println(lastFile.getName());
```